# 404 error when post in Postman

Tags: spring, postman

I´m trying to send a POST request that is an `Person` object that contains a list of contacts.
But I don´t know if this is the correct syntax to send a list:

```
 {
    "name":"romulo",
    "contacts" :  [ 
        { 
            "contact" : "3466577" 

        },
            { 
            "contact" : "532423" 

            }
        ]
    }
```

But keeps me returning a 404 error

what i´m doing wrong?

post method:

```
@PostMapping("/person")
public void addPerson(@Valid @RequestBody Person person) {
    Person savedPerson = personRepository.save(person);
    List<Contact> contacts = person.getContacts();
    for (Contact contact1 : contacts) {
        contactRepository.save(contact1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well is there any documentation on this API, and, if so, have you checked it?

Comment: I think it must return `ResponseBody`, current method return nothing, therefore 404 error is rationale.

Comment: It´s a test that i´m trying to do:Contact List
Create a REST API which will store people and their contacts. A person can have multiple
contacts such as phone, email or whatsapp. The API should allow to create, update, get
and delete both the people and the contacts.

Comment: I tried to return a Person object, but nothing has changed.I am mapping something wrong?

Comment: We need more details about what address are you trying to call. Spring returns 404 when the endpoint is not found.

Answer (score 6):

In My Case it was simple mistake and spend an hour for figuring it out that i had space at the end of my url.

Comment: In my case, I had a space at the end of my endpoint url and I had removed that in Postman :V

Answer (score 4):

HTTP 404 is returned when the server is unable to find method to match your exact request.

For the mentioned request have the url as `http://<context>/requestpath` with request method as POST.(`http://localhost:8080/person`)

Check the request body and all the fields should exactly match the Person object else it may return HTPP 400.

Comment: Hi there,thanks for the answer.The correct url is :http://localhost:8080/api/person because of the base url mapping @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ContactController. i tried to put all the fields but is still not working:   {
"personId": 1  
"name":"romulo",
"contacts" :  [ 
 { 
  "id":1
  "contact" : "3466577" 
  
 },
  { 
  "contact" : "532423" 
  
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL you are making the POST request to is correct.

In my example I was getting the same error when doing a GET request.

I was making call to the URL: http://localhost:5000/RefreshToken,

The correct URL was: http://localhost:5000/auth/RefreshToken